# Error handling in Boost Spirit symbol table

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit

Assuming I have symbol table like this:

```
struct jass_types : qi::symbols<char, jass_type> {
```

now I want to fill a customly declared type with its parent type:

```
identifier %= 
    char_("a-zA-Z") >> -(*char_("a-zA-Z_0-9") >> char_("a-zA-Z0-9"))
    ;

type %=
    lit("type") >> identifier >>
    lit("extends") >> identifier[type_symbols.find(_1)]
```

the structure is as followed:

```
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
wc3lib::jass::jass_type,
(std::string, identifier)
(wc3lib::jass::jass_type*, parent)
)
```

how do I have to write my code that it stores 0 into attribute "parent" if the identifier after "extends" is not found in the symbol table and how do I react to missing symbols properly?

My idea was to make something like:

```
boost::variant<wc3lib::jass::jass_type*,std::string> parent
```

and to fill either the pointer or the identifier depending on the fact if the type was found in the symbol table or not but I would have to detect the typeinformation of parent afterwards.
Another option would be to store 0 for parent as mentoined and to create an error object with the identifier information etc. maybe Boost does already the same thing if a symbol is not found???

**edit:**

Firstly made the error of using _2 instead of _1 but it still won't work since it apparently needs a char* value instead of std::string, so I added a custom function:

```
inline jass_type* get_type_symbol(jass_types &types, const std::string &value) {
    return types.find(value.c_str());
}
```

and a semantic action:

```
type =
    lit("type") >> identifier >>
    lit("extends") >> identifier[phoenix::bind(&get_type_symbol, ref(type_symbols), _1)]
    ;
```

but it still seems to be overcomplicated this way and I couldn't solve the problem of proper error detection/storage of identifier if symbol is not found!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
// simplified identifier rule exposes a `std::strirng`:
qi::rule<It, std::string()> identifier = char_("a-zA-Z") >> *char_("a-zA-Z_0-9");

struct jass_types : qi::symbols<char, jass_type*> {
        // ...
};

typedef boost::variant<jass_type*, std::string> jass_typeref;
jass_types type_symbols;
```

Note that I made the `symbols<>` parser just return a pointer to the jass_type directly. Now the rule could be as simple as:

```
qi::rule<It, jass_typeref()> typeref_ = type_symbols | identifier;
```

Use it e.g. as

```
type %= "type" >> identifier >> "extends" >> typeref_;
```

To supply a default, you could do

```
type %= "type" >> identifier >> 
        ("extends" >> typeref_ | qi::attr(std::string("::object")));
```

(assuming all types ultimate extend `::object`)